# Wordpress Insert Text Link After Each post

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I want to add a text link automatically after each post.
I use this code in `functions.php`

```
function insertFootLink($content) {
    $content.= get_template_part( 'download','link');
    return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'insertFootLink');
```

Everything is OK, but the Text Link is inserted ABOVE the content, not AFTER.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `get_template_part()` here, as it doesn't `return` anything. Instead, you'll need to include the file as a string (since the `$content` is also a string).

Assuming the file isn't executable PHP, one way to do this would be to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).